# For what reason to change the position of this line generates a different assignment in variable?

Tags: c

In the two codes below should happen exactly the same:

```
struct people {
    char name[25];
    int age;
};

void save() {
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("things.sve", "wb");

    struct people myself;
    strcpy(myself.name, "Bruno Macabeus");
    myself.age = 18;

    struct people fox;
    strcpy(fox.name, "Megan Fox");
    fox.age = 22;

    struct people luffy;
    strcpy(luffy.name, "Monkey D. Luffy");
    luffy.age = 20;

    int totalPeople = 3;
    struct people some[2];
    some[0] = myself;
    some[1] = fox;
    some[2] = luffy;

    fwrite(&totalPeople, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    //fwrite(some, sizeof(struct people), 3, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

and

```
struct people {
    char name[25];
    int age;
};

void save() {
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("things.sve", "wb");

    struct people myself;
    strcpy(myself.name, "Bruno Macabeus");
    myself.age = 18;

    struct people fox;
    strcpy(fox.name, "Megan Fox");
    fox.age = 22;

    struct people luffy;
    strcpy(luffy.name, "Monkey D. Luffy");
    luffy.age = 20;

    struct people some[2];
    some[0] = myself;
    some[1] = fox;
    some[2] = luffy;
    int totalPeople = 3;

    fwrite(&totalPeople, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    //fwrite(some, sizeof(struct people), 3, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I only changed the boot time of the variable "totalPeople", however, this creates a big change when I saved it. In the first case, save something strange: "66 66 79 00". In the second case, it works: "03 00 00 00".

For what reason acontence this? It should not work in both cases? How to solve this problem?

Comment: The way the function and it's data is arranged in memory is causing it because you are altering the place where `totalPeople` is stored by writing beyond `some` array bounds.

Comment: In other words `struct people some[2]` defines array `some` with `2` elements: `some[0], some[1]`. When you assign `some[2] = luffy` you have written beyond the end of your `some` array causing **undefined behavior**. Fix the definition of `some` (i.e. `struct people some[3];`) for your code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are accessing array `some` out of bounds. It is an array of 2 elements,

```
struct people some[2];
```

and you treat it as if it had 3.

```
some[2] = luffy;
```

That causes *undefined behaviour*. The solution is to not access arrays out of bounds.